# Opencv - how use the same window with the imshow() method shared with many threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

My code below works sometimes and sometimes it does not work as expected. Basically I created a pool of threads that should present the images in a single window. To achieve this effect, each group of threads method call imshow (windowName) with the same name (windowName variable). So each thread group has a specific window where the image should be displayed.

However when running the application, sometimes more than one window is shown to the same thread group. I believe what should be happening is that the first thread prepares the window, then changes state giving way to another thread, then this second thread prepares another window (since the first is not ready yet) and after complete all process two windows appear.

What would be a good solution to ensure that only the first thread starts imshow()?
Maybe this approach is wrong or not good solution, and I would like know about this!

Part of code is below:

```
    int processVideo(char * videoFileName, char * projectNameIn, vector<SelectedRegion> * v_region, char * configPar) {

        char mainWindowName[100];
        static char threadWindow[sizeof(mainWindowName)];
        //Some code here
        sprintf_s(mainWindowName, "ImageProc[Thread Session ID: %00d]", config.threadGroupSession);
        //Some code here
        cv::Mat videoFrameFeed;

        while(capture.read(videoFrameFeed) && !terminateApp){
            //Some code here
            imshow(mainWindowName, videoFrameFeed);
            //Some code here
        }
   }
```

Comment: use `cv::namedWindow` in the main thread and let the threads only use `cv::imshow` on their (previously created) windownames.

Comment: in addition: remind that openCVs highgui isnt meant to be used for end user needs but only for fast mechanisms to test/visualize your project during development. If you are beyong that state, switch to some real gui... Qt or something like that.

Comment: @Micka tks for your comments. Are very useful. But, in the first comment you say to use namedWindow only for main thread. How know if the thread is "main" in the code? I solve the problem momentarily creating a lock session, based on your comment to only a main thread use the and adding a global variable. But I'm not sure if this is a good strategy. I put the code how another answer.

Comment: somewhere you compute the number of threads you will create (later) and group them into blocks I guess? Let the program create the window when it creates a new block.

Answer (score 0):

After read some comments, I create one lock thread session to solve. Works fine. I will put the code bellow to help another people.

```
//Global Variable
bool global_llock_for_thread = false;

void look_session_image_proc(){
    while(global_llock_for_thread){
        //wait for unlook;
    }

    global_llock_for_thread = true;
}

void unlook_session_image_proc(){
    global_llock_for_thread = false;
}
```

After that I add the code bellow.

```
while(capture.read(videoFrameFeed) && !terminateApp){
    //Some code here
    unlook_session_image_proc();

    imshow(mainWindowName, videoFrameFeed);

    unlook_session_image_proc();

    //Some code here
}
```